# importing an object within an object from an API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users. Within the address object theres a geo object i tried importing it by this method, which shows nothing on the webpage.

```
{identity.address && identity.geo && (
            <div>
              <b>Lat: </b> {identity.address.geo.lat}
            </div>
            )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing an object within an object I believe you have to reference the parent first.
So

`identity.geo`

should instead be

```
identity.address.geo
```

Answer (score 0):

ok found the solution, turns out i should map the whole path on the second import

```
{identity.address && identity.address.geo && (

            ...
)}
```